# How to list all files/directories from ftp server in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, ftp, filesystems

I'm using ftp as a filesystem driver.

```
'ftp' => [
        'driver' => 'ftp',
        'host' => 'myip',
        'username' => 'myusername',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'passive' => true,
        'ssl' => true,
        'passive' => true,
        'timeout' => 30,
        // Optional FTP Settings...
        // 'port' => 21,
        // 'root' => '',
        // 'passive' => true,
        // 'ssl' => true,
        // 'timeout' => 30,
    ],
```

I can upload in this ftp server but cannot list or dowload anything beacause of

> File not found at path

My code for listing is this:

```
Storage::files()
```

When I try to do it with PHP functions it works! I need to do this with Storage laravel functions

```
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect("myip");
$login = ftp_login($conn_id, "myusername", "mypassword");
$file_list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "."); // this works like a charm and Yes, I tried to do Storage::files('.') as well !
```

Comment: Have you installed the Flysystem FTP package as per the laravel docs?

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#ftp-driver-configuration

Comment: Yes. Uploading files is working very well. I'm only having a hard time fetching and dowloading

Comment: Alright, in the Laravel docs it also says that when using `files()` method you need to specify a directory like so `Storage::files($directory);`. I suppose for listing everything in the FTP server you would specify the root directory of your server.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#get-all-files-within-a-directory

Comment: My root directory is /, there is no subdirectory in it

Comment: I understand but since `Storage::files($directory);` seems to expect a directory, I suppose passing in the root directory would work and then list all files in the root directory. That's what I piece together from the documentation atleast, I haven't used the Laravel FTP storage driver.

In turn you could try the following and see if that works:
`Storage::disk('ftp')->files();`

Comment: I tried also Storage::disk('ftp')->files('/'); but it returns empty array

Comment: And removing the '/' in `files('/');` ?

Comment: Same, Storage::exists($directory) works though, but  Storage::exists($filePath) don't. Idk